# How Do I Exclude Package Files (Directories) from Bash Mac find?

Tags: bash, macos, find

**How do I exclude Mac Package files from the search path of the Bash find command?**

The macOS has some "files" that are really unix directories.  These are called "packages".  A Mac app file is a great example, but there are others.  Unfortunately, I don't see any find switches to exclude packages.

Here's a typical find command that does NOT work.  It will search inside the .app files:

```
find /Applications -type f -path ./*.app -prune -o  -print
```

In this case I want it to list the actual .app files, but NOT search inside of them.

I have tried many variations of this, and none have worked.

Here are some other typical file extensions that are really packages:
`.app   .pkg   .scptd`

Comment: Down-voting answers from folk trying to help you will not endear you, nor encourage them or others to answer you in future. Especially when the answer just didn't do what you want because of your over-simplistic example. Less useful answers will automatically sink to the bottom anyway when other, more relevant ones appear - smacking them over the head with a sledgehammer is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert a regex criterion that returns false for all content within a package directory.  Unfortunately, it does mean having to list the file extensions of the package directories whose contents you wish to exclude.  I've listed quite a few of them in my regex string:

```
find -E /Applications ! -iregex '.*\.(app(download)?|scptd|pkg|bundle|qlgenerator|c?action|dictionary|cannedSearch|photoslibrary)/.+'
```

Comment: Thanks, CJK, that seems to do the job, but it is not the fastest tool I've ever run.  It took about 12 sec on my speedy iMac-27 that is usually fast.

Comment: Yes, the more file extensions it has to consider, the slower the process.  If you are mostly using this tool to search directories that you're confident consist of particular package types, you would be better removing the less common ones from that list to speed it up.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I got a bundle test from another answer (from user [anonymous-coward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1641442/anonymous-coward)). Put it into a little script and call it "bundle", as in the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

content_tree=$(mdls -name kMDItemContentTypeTree "$@" | grep -E '\"com.apple.bundle\"')

[[ ! -z "$content_tree" ]] && exit 0 || exit 1
```

(Feel free to improve my bash.) Bundle returns 0 (success) if the argument is a path to a bundle and 1 otherwise. It generates some Mac-specific meta data and looks for the bundle characteristic. If you wish to more specifically avoid packages and not bundles of other kinds, you can look for "com.apple.package". Your `bundle` script can select for anything you want. Run `mdls -name kMDItemContentTypeTree` on some files and see what emerges, and that will tell you what regex to pass to `grep`. You could put additional tests, for things like file extensions, and so forth. Then form your `find`command like this:

```
find /Applications \( -exec bundle {} \; -print -prune \) -or -print
```

I just used `Applications` because it's an example of where you'll find a lot of bundles and packages. The `-exec` tag returns false if the shell result is not 0 (because 0 always means "success" as a shell result). So, the expression on the left of `-or` means that if something IS a bundle, we will print its full path and the `-prune` means we will NOT proceed into the directory. The seemingly redundant `-print` to the right of the `-or` is because if you use `-exec` or some other operators, `find` suppresses all default printing, so you need to explicitly print the path if it is a bundle (or package or whatever your script detects) and also print the path if it's not. NOTE: it is key that you use `\;` and not `+` at the end of the test before `-print` and `-prune`. Otherwise `find` will group lots of files to pass to `bundle` and you need to get one answer per file. You can replace the `-print` operators with an `-exec` on either side of the `-or` or both sides, in case you want to process the files in some way other than just hunting them down. Turns out this is an example of any two classes of files that you want to process differently. Hope this is useful. It was a fun exercise, and actually very interesting in terms of thinking about forming `find` expressions.

Answer (score 0):

To dovetail with **@cycollins** excellent answer, here's an alternate form of the helper script (as well as a negated flavor) that are a tiny bit more concise:

save this as **`is_bundle`** somewhere in your `$PATH` :

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
mdls -name kMDItemContentTypeTree "$1" | egrep -q '\"com.apple.(bundle|package)\"'
```

and save this as **`is_not_bundle`** :

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
mdls -name kMDItemContentTypeTree "$1" | egrep -q '\"com.apple.(bundle|package)\"'
[ $? -eq 0 ] && exit 1 || exit 0
```

**Here are some usage examples:**

- Find *directories only* that contain `<pattern>` (omits bundles completely)

  `find -s . -type d -iname "*pattern*" -exec is_not_bundle {} \; -print`
- Find anything containing `<pattern>` — don't descend into bundles:

  `find -s . -iname "*pattern*" \( -exec is_bundle {} \; -print -prune -or -print \)`
- Find directories *or* bundles (but don't descend into them)

  `find -s . -type d -mindepth 1 \( -exec is_bundle {} \; -print -prune -or -print \)`
- Find **only** bundles

  `find -s . -type d -exec is_bundle {} \; -print -prune`
- Find bundles matching `<pattern>`

  `find -s . -iname "*pattern*" -exec is_bundle {} \; -print -prune`